# Compactness of the unit ball in $L_1([0,1]^2) $ restricted to finite dimensions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am trying to understand if the unit closed ball in L_1([0,1]^2) restricted to finite dimensions is compact or not.

Let me give some definitions.

Let $m$ be a positive integer. Let $P^{(m)}=\{ x \in [0,1]^m: \sum_i x_i =1\}$ be the simplex of discrete probability vectors.
Let $\nu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$,  let $S=\{S_1, \cdots, S_m\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$  where every $S_i$ is connected,  let $\pi \in P^{(m)}$ such that $\nu(S_i)=\pi_i$, let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times }m$ be a matrix on $\mathbb{R}$. Then an $m$-stepfunction $(A,\pi):[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function locally constant on  $S_i \times S_j$ for all $i,j \in [m]$,  defined by
$$
(A,\pi)(x,y) = \sum_{i,j=1}^m A_{i,j}I((x,y) \in S_i \times S_j )
$$
We denote the space of $m$-stepfunctions by $W^{(m)}$.
Hence the $1$-norm of $L^1([0,1]^2)$ restricted to $W^{(m)}$ has the form,
$$
\|(A,\pi) \|^1_1 = \sum_{i,j=1}^m |A_{i,j}| \pi_i \pi_j 
$$
Hence we define the unit ball $B(0,1)=\{(A,\pi) \in W^{(m)}: \|(A,\pi) \|^1_1 \leq 1 \}$ in $ W^{(m)}$. $B(0,1)$ can also be seen as subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m} \times P^{(m)} $.

From the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m} \times P^{(m)}, $ $B(0,1)$  is not bounded thus it is not compact.

Now. Let $(A_1, \pi_i), (A_2, \pi_2) \in W^{(m)}$, then $d((A_1, \pi_i), (A_2, \pi_2)) = \int_{[0,1]^2} |A_1, \pi_i)(x,y) - (A_2, \pi_2)(x,y)| dxdy $.

I wonder if the unit ball in $L_1([0,1]^2) \cap W^{(m)}$  i.e. $B_1(0,1)=\{(A,\pi): d((A,\pi),0) = 1\}$ is compact in the topology inherited by $L_1([0,1]^2)$ in $W^{(m)}$.

Comment: Can you find $2$-isolated infinite subset of $B(0,1)$?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on how $B(0,1)$ can be considered a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m} \times P^{(m)}$? Doesn't $(A,\pi)$ also depend on the choice of $S$?

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets I can not find  2-isolated infinite subset of B(0,1), since B(0,1) is connected. Note that every pair of points in B(0,1)  can be connected by a  two-segment line connecting the origin.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets If $S$ has null sets then we can rearrange the part of $S$ say $S_1$ such that the corresponding stepfunction $(A_1, \pi_1)$ is a different finite-dimensional vector than $(A,\pi)$ but they can be the same function. However, it does not change that B(0,1) can be seen as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m} \times P^{(m)}$.

Comment: We might be using different definition of $\epsilon$-isolated points. What I meant is an infinite set $X$ such that $||x-y|| \geq 2$ for all $x \neq y$ in $X$. This can happen in connected spaces, for example $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and even numbers are $2$-isolated set.

Comment: What I meant by my second question is, whether we fix $S$ in the begining and consider only $m$-step function with respect to $S$. For example if we take $S_1 = \{[0,1/2) ; \;  [1/2,1]\}$ and $S_2 = \{[0,1/4] \cup [3/4,1] ; \; (1/4,3/4)\}$, then these partitions will have the same $\pi$ but the corresponding $m$-step functions will be different.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets. I don't see that $B(0,1)$ contains an infinite 2-isolated infinite subset.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets.. Good observation. So I added in the question that the parts of $S$ must be connected.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\widetilde{f_n} = I((x,y) \in [\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+1}]^2)$ and $f_n = \frac{\widetilde{f_n}}{||\widetilde{f_n}||_1}$. Then

1. $f_n \in B(0,1)$,
2. $||f_n-f_m||_1 = 2$ as for $n \neq m$ the functions $f_n$ and $f_m$ have disjoint supports (up to a null set, of course).

Hence, $B(0,1)$ is not compact as it contains an infinite isolated subset (or, by standard definition of compactness, the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $B(0,1)$ has no convergent subsequences).

Also note that the space $W^{(m)}$ is not of finite dimesnion.

Comment: The sequence $f_n$ is not contained in $W^{(m)}$ since $m$ (the number of parts of $S$) is fixed.

Comment: Doesn't $S$ have three parts for all $n>2$? @jaogye

Comment: $S$ has three parts only when $m=3$. $W^{(m)}$ has $m^2+m-1$ dimensions.   @KeeperOfSecrets

Comment: I guess I have misunderstood the difinition of $W^{(m)}$ then.